# Mongo query not producing results in my main server

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, promise

I tried to make use of promises to get all the items from my mongoDB database.
This is my code:

```
exports.findAll = function(){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      Collection.find({}, function(err, res){
        if(err){
          reject(err);
        } else {
          console.log(res);
          resolve(res);
        }
      });
  });
}
```

However, when I call the `findAll()` function, the result is an empty array. I have checked my connection to the database, and it is successfully established. And the database itself is non-empty too. I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [mongoose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose) for comfortable use of MongoDB

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
```

Create a connection

```
await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/my_database', {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useFindAndModify: false,
  useCreateIndex: true
});
```

Create your model for the collection

```
const collection= new Schema({
  _id: ObjectId,
  name: String,
  age: Number,
});

const Collection= mongoose.model('Collection', collection);


const data = await Collection.find({});
```

[Here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) you can find more information check Mongoose documentation

Comment: Thanks for the help! However, using mongoose doesn't seem to solve my problem. I have successfully established a connection using mongoose and it seems to run perfectly when I'm running other queries like `findOne()`, but I'm unable to produce a result using promises in my `findAll()` function. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: And what about `find()?`

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I meant `find()` and not `findAll()`. The problem seems to be with the way I have constructed the promise. In a test project, where I hadn't made use of promises, all the functions works fine.

Comment: `console.log(res)` logging an empty array?

Comment: Yup, and `console.log(err)` yields `null`.

Comment: But if you used mongoose, you don't need to add `find` in the promise. You can just call it using await. Can You check without it?

Comment: Alright, I'll try to do that. Thank you for your help!